# Assigns me no mail after user creation - Does Logic Apps make a mistake?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

This is the case, for example, if a user now creates a page. So the next day I need Azure Logic apps to send an email after 1 day.

The problem is: right now, it is by no means sending any email to me if I sign up yesterday. But it sends me an email that now it has gone through with succe.

I would like to know what goes wrong since it by no means email me as I set up yesterday.

[My Logic app (From Azure) - Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g08fK.png)

However, be aware that the code can be made short but I just need to find out if Logic apps are making mistakes or if thus my code previously works without problems.

```
[Route("/api/cronjob")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NewSletterUserEmail()
    {
        await Newsletter();

        return Ok("Godkendt!");
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> Newsletter()
    {
        var m = new Settings.ArdklarMail();

        var dtt = DateTime.Now;
        var days = _dbContext.OfferUser.Max(i => i.Days);
        var MaxDays = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-days);

        var userlist = _dbContext.Users.Where(i => i.Opretdate >= MaxDays && i.TilmeldtNyhedsbrev == true).ToList();
        if (userlist != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in userlist)
            {
                string mail = item.Brugernavn;
                string fullname = item.Navn;

                var memberData = _dbContext.MemberShipValue.FirstOrDefault(r => r.UserId == item.UserId);
                if (memberData == null)
                {
                    //alm bruger
                    var result = _dbContext.OfferUser.Where(x => x.Value == 1).ToList();
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var itemValue in result)
                        {
                            int itemValueDays = itemValue.Days;//hvis den ingen antal har så giver den 0.
                            var daysValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-itemValueDays);


                            if (item.Opretdate.Date == daysValue)
                            {
                                var title = itemValue.Title;

                                var viewModel = new EmailModel
                                {
                                    getUrl = m.RemoveLinkUrl(),
                                    Title = title,
                                    FullName = fullname,
                                    Text = itemValue.Text.ToHtmlString()
                                };


                                var resultMail = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Templates/OfferToUsers.cshtml", viewModel);//return Null here

                                MailMessageControl mailA = new MailMessageControl();
                                mailA.SetCredentials(m.azureName(), m.password());
                                mailA.SetSender(m.mailFrom());
                                mailA.AddAddressSee(item.Brugernavn);
                                mailA.SetSubject(title);
                                mailA.SetBody(resultMail);

                                mailA.SendEmail();
                                await Task.Delay(2200);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = _dbContext.OfferUser.Where(x => x.Value == 2).ToList();
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var itemValue in result)
                        {
                            int itemValueDays = itemValue.Days;//hvis den ingen antal har så giver den 0.
                            var daysValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-itemValueDays);


                            if (item.Opretdate.Date == daysValue)
                            {
                                var title = itemValue.Title;

                                var viewModel = new EmailModel
                                {
                                    getUrl = m.RemoveLinkUrl(),
                                    Title = title,
                                    FullName = fullname,
                                    Text = itemValue.Text.ToHtmlString()
                                };

                                var resultMail = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Templates/OfferToUsers.cshtml", viewModel);//return Null here

                                MailMessageControl mailA = new MailMessageControl();
                                mailA.SetCredentials(m.azureName(), m.password());
                                mailA.SetSender(m.mailFrom());
                                mailA.AddAddressSee(item.Brugernavn);
                                mailA.SetSubject(title);
                                mailA.SetBody(resultMail);

                                mailA.SendEmail();
                                await Task.Delay(2200);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Det er til dem fra nyhedsbrevet som få tilsendt nyhedsbrev omkring div ting.
        var newsletterlist = _dbContext.NewsletterList.Where(i => i.Tilmeldtdato >= MaxDays).ToList();
        if (newsletterlist != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in newsletterlist)
            {
                string mail = item.Email;
                string fullname = item.Email;

                //til de nyhedsbrevet område
                var result = _dbContext.OfferUser.Where(x => x.Value == 3).ToList();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    foreach (var itemValue in result)
                    {
                        int itemValueDays = itemValue.Days;
                        var daysValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-itemValueDays);


                        if (item.Tilmeldtdato.Date == daysValue)
                        {
                            var title = itemValue.Title;

                            var viewModel = new EmailModel
                            {
                                getUrl = m.RemoveLinkUrl(),
                                Title = title,
                                FullName = fullname,
                                Text = itemValue.Text.ToHtmlString()
                            };

                            var resultMail = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Templates/OfferToUsers.cshtml", viewModel);

                            MailMessageControl mailA = new MailMessageControl();
                            mailA.SetCredentials(m.azureName(), m.password());
                            mailA.SetSender(m.mailFrom());
                            mailA.AddAddressSee(mail);
                            mailA.SetSubject(title);
                            mailA.SetBody(resultMail);

                            mailA.SendEmail();

                            await Task.Delay(3500);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return Ok("Godkendt!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't see mistake in Azure Logic Apps. Since the Logic App uses a recurrence trigger, it triggers the Logic App at the defined interval of time.

As there was send email action both side on the parallel branch, it will somehow send you an email by no means.